# Transaction timeouts supported for Neo4j 1.9.8?

Tags: neo4j

Does Neo4j 1.9.8 support transaction timeouts?

I see some references to the setting:

org.neo4j.server.transaction.timeout=60

but it looks like it's only available in Neo4j 2.x. Ultimately, I'm looking for a way to abort a long-running transaction, and thinking that the server-wide transaction timeout is the way to go.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned config setting only applies to the new [transactional http endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) that was introduced in Neo4j 2.0.

There is another feature call guards being available in 1.x as well. Please be aware that guards are non-public API and therefore subject to change. See http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/17/neo4j-setting-query-timeout/ for some information how to use them.